# Migration : change integer to reference without loosing lines

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, migration

I'm working on an existing project and I need to change to type of an existing field. This field was declared as

```
add_column :users, :fo_creator, :integer
```

But as fo_creator field is a reference to the users table I need to change it to :

```
add_reference :user, :fo_creator, index: true
```

How can I do it without loosing datas saved

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want. Do you need to add an index to the column? If `fo_creator` is the reference to another model you have to define the relationship at the model, you don't need to modify the database. Can you explain a little better what are your models, what's the relationship, what you have now and what you expect it to be? It's not too clear right now

Comment: Actually in the table users I have a integer field fo_creator which reference a user. The problem when I can't set a relation belongs_to in the model, then I believe is because the field was created by using an integer, then I'm trying to find a way to use reference

Comment: `The problem when I can't set a relation belongs_to in the model` what error are you getting? keys for belongs_to are integers (`add_reference` method adds an integer just using some conventions). Show your models, you can set the relationships, you just need to tell ActiveRecord the class name and the column name and it works.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing magical about the columns created by the `references` macro.

`references :fo_creator` creates:

- a bigint `fo_creator_id` column
- a foreign key

The reason your association does not work is most likely that `belongs_to :fo_creator` assumes the fkey column is named `:fo_creator_id`. While this can be changed by providing the `foreign_key` option I would say you are right to rename the column to remove this inconsistency.

You can salvage your existing column by renaming the column and adding a foreign key:

```
class ChangeUsersFoCreatorToReference < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    rename_column :users, :fo_creator, :fo_creator_id
    change_column :users, :fo_creator_id, :bigint # optional
    add_foreign_key :users, :fo_creators
  end
end
```

If `fo_creator_id` is self referencing (references the users table) you need to create the fk as so:

```
# from table, to table
add_foreign_key :users, :users, column: :fo_creator_id
```

See:

- [ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SchemaStatements#add_reference](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_reference)
- [ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods#belongs_to](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to)
- [ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SchemaStatements#add_foreign_key](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_foreign_key)

Comment: Great comment. As I'm new to ruby and Rails, you gave a great explanation. I'll test it monday :)